# photoshop - cut and move part of a shape layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

In photoshop, i have a "speech bubble" of sorts.

I need to be able to move the little triangle bit of the bubble left, right, and to the side.

Then "rejoin" it with the rectangle, and apply all the gradent/bevel effects of the original.

photoshop has a selector tool, but i cannot seem to cut, coppy, delete with it - actually, i do not understand *why* the rectangle selector exists (unless maybe there is a market for people who like pretty transient rectangles?)

So, for pictures -

this is the intial image i want to move around:
[image: this is the intial image i want to move around:]

this is the image with all the  stuff removed, i just want to move that triangle around!!
[image: this is the image with all the stuff removed, i just want to move that triangle around!!]

And then of course reapply the effects that i disabled. I imagine this is a super simple job - how do i do this?

Comment: I'd suggest you actually redraw the shape. Would you like help doing that? You basically have to use the round corner rectangle tool and the polygon tool for the little triangle.

Comment: i mean, if it is easy to do i would like help, yes. i just thought that moving the triangle around and then reapplying all the filters would be the simplest!

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have this as a shape layer, you can easily select the points (Direct Selection Tool) and hold shift to move your triangle area.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2):

This shape would actually take very little time to recreate, so I suggest you draw it from scratch:

- Draw a round corner rectangle using the `Rounded Rectangle Tool`
- Draw a triangle using the `Polygon Tool`
- Join both shapes together (you can do this by copy-pasting the triangle on the rectangle layer, for example).
- Apply your gradient.

Now you can move the triangle (use the `Path Selection Tool` to do this) around the rectangle and the gradient will be applied to the entire new shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to manipulate a Shape. You have to rasterize the shape first. Right click on the layer of the shape in the Layer list and choose "Raterize". Then use the rectangle marquee tool to move the point around. The layer effects will be applied automatically.

Comment: you are a genius! what does "rasterize" do? Is it just graphic-code for "Make Normal"???

Comment: The shape was a vector shape. You can't affect vector shapes with pixel tools, because they don't contain any pixels. `Rasterize` makes the vector shape into actual pixels you *can* manipulate.

Comment: @bharal Basically, a shape is a mathematical representation of an illustrated object. With points and direction of lines between the points. Manipulating such an object can be done in the points (point manipulating tool, shortcut A) but not in areas between the points. Rasterize basically means "transform to pixels". The object is then consisted of a grid of pixels, where each individual pixel has no "relation" to any other pixel. Therefore there's no problem manipulating isolated parts of such an object.

Comment: @bharal I would not recommend rasterizing. See the other answers.

Comment: @Scott just out of keen interest, why shouldn't bharal rasterize?

Comment: Because you *lose* editability when you rasterize. Rasterizing is destructive. In addition, the overall shape of shape layers or vector layers are *exceptionally easy* to edit when compared to raster layers. As I pointed out, see the other answers here. They explain editing while at the same time **maintaining** the quality of the original artwork.

Comment: @Scott but maintaining the quality is redundant if you already have your size. Not sure why I'm telling you this but the shapes are rasterized either way when exported. If you select and move the arrow you're sure of it keeping its size. If you're moving a second shape around, getting it to "point out" the same on each direction, is more tricky. I definitely stick to raster as being the most convenient approach.

Comment: Okay.. you use what you use and I'll stick to what I know works. No problem. There's no point in discussing the merits of vector shapes over raster shapes if you aren't already aware of them. It's too long of a conversation for comments.

Comment: @Scott Ok, I won't be obstinate. I realize keeping it as a vector shape does provide more flexibility and that rasterization is destructive. My answer was the answer to the OP, *why the point couldn't be moved around*. I won't debate there being more correct approaches when dealing with this task.

Comment: Providing somewhat bad, short-sighted, steps to solve a problem on the spot which then may result in further issues later was a less than desirable answer in my opinion. Sort of like someone asking... "How do I keep my neighbor's dog from barking?" and the short-sighted answer being, "Shoot it." Yes it solves the issue, but it is not a good long-term solution.

Comment: Telling some just to "rasterize it" may solve the issue right now. But what happens when they save the file and close it? Then a week later need the same shape but the arrow in yet another position and the gradient at a different angle/color? Or need a slightly larger image? They open their file only to realize what *was* easy to edit is now ultimately more complicated due to the rasterization.

Comment: @Scott One question, does the OP now know WHY shapes can't have areas manipulated using the regular selection tool? The answer to that is yes, because I told him. I think understanding the fundamentals of the object composition is far more constructive than tailoring for an ad hoc use case.

Comment: I'm with Scott on this one. Yes @AndroidHustle, you did tell him _why_ he couldn't manipulate the shape, but then you told him he "had to" convert the shape in order to accomplish his goal rather than _how to manipulate it in its current form_. Strictly speaking, your answer is misleading and incorrect, and certainly not making the best use of the software.  Using the vector tools, he could do a lot more than slide the rasterized triangle around, something he'd probably really appreciate (especially considering it's a speech bubble that probably wants pointing in specific directions).